# How do I get a list of the same dates from the first two cols, then get the value of the third cols in a new DataFrame?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a data frame, the first col is the date of heavy pollution day(HODate), the second col (WTDate) is each day of the year with information of weather type in the third column(TYPE).
I would like to get the weather type for each heavy pollution day in a new list.

The example data frame:

[image]

I'm a new python learner. I tried to use intersection code. It can only return the duplicate dates. How do I improve the code to get the result that I expect? Now, I only can output the duplicate date.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(f), columns= ['HODate','WTDate','Type'])
df1 = df.loc[~df['HODate'].duplicated(keep = False), ['HODate']]
```

My expected result is to keep the HODate and their weather type.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In Excel the function below would produce the result you want.
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH($A2,B:B,0))
This presumes that the 3 columns you introduced are columns A:C and that column B does indeed contain a date equal to the one in A2.